# Issue in Jmeter Regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to extract a substring from the below mentioned html tag,but i cannot extract the substring.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked" tabindex="true" value="28744628*Postpaid" onclick="disSelectCheckBox();">
```

from the above tags i want to extract the substring 28744628,and for this i am trying the following regular expressions:

```html
1)<input type="checkbox" name="checked" tabindex="true" value="(.+?)*Postpaid" onclick="disSelectCheckBox();"
```

--> if i use this expression no value is being retreived.

```html
2)<input type="checkbox" name="checked" tabindex="true" value="(.+?)" onclick="disSelectCheckBox();"
```

--> if i use this expression the whole string(28744628*Postpaid) is extracted,where as i want only the substring(28744628).

Can you provide any inputs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value="(.+?)\*Postpaid
            ^
```

Escape your `*`.It is a quantifier.It means `0 or more times`.`(.+?)*` in effect gives no ouput as `+?*` forms catastrophic backtracking.And your regex might be unable to complete.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/22